# Windows ghost file handles

Tags: windows-10, filesystems

I am intermittently having issues in Windows 10 where all files or folders on a certain drive and sometimes certain subdirectories get a write lock.  This is happening on a separate drive from the drive where Windows is installed and whenever it happens, I have to move the folder or file into another directory, rename it, then move it back.  I have tried using handle and performance monitor to see if there are any handles on the files or directories and there never are.  This used to happen on the root of my G drive which is a compressed NTFS drive but eventually this problem went away.  It hasn't happened in a while and just now it was happening in a subdirctory on that drive.  As stated above, there were no handles attached to the affected files but moving those files to another directory, renaming them, then moving them back was a solution but obviously this can become a pain when having to do it often.  I have also tried using CMD to rename affected directories but this doesn't work either.

I've searched around for a solution to this on and off for quite some time and every time I see solutions like see what the file is open in and like I've said, there is no indication that the files are open.  I've also tested things like making a new folder and trying to rename it and it never works.  I always have to move it to another directory and rename it and then move it back.  It seems like there is some sort of lock but this should prevent me from moving the files but that works.  From what I've seen in the past, locks prevent moving files but allow copying them an moving works here.

Comment: Does this happen in Safe Mode?

Comment: I haven't tested in safe mode, it happens intermittently and a reboot always fixes it.  I haven't determined what causes it and sometimes it just stops happening without any obvious change.

Comment: try to find out of it happens I'm safe mode. This is the fault of 3rd party software.

Comment: I would try to see if it happens in safe mode but I don't know the trigger.  This typically only happens maybe once a month at what seems to be random, it may be right after a reboot or after days of runtime.  If I had any idea of what caused it, I'd attempt to replicate it in safe mode.

Comment: This may be unrelated but on occasion I get system lockups that seem to be related to the system having really high read or write speed.  This may happen when windows update it working or when malwarebytes is scanning.  I will be able to move my mouse but nothing responds at all, it doesn't even show the not responding indicator, it just doesn't do anything and after a few moments everything goes back to normal.  SMART status says all is good too.  Even more rarely, my system will lock up and once it is corrected, all text on my system is gone or glitched.

Comment: Do you have any backup software running that may be preventing the files from changing as it backs them up? (You'd hope it used Shadow Copy, but it's worth checking).

Comment: I do not have any third party backup software and have never enabled windows backup software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was Foobar2000 being weird, for whatever reason it does't show that it has handles on every file in a folder but when I close it it seems to allow me to rename folders.  This still doesn't explain why I can't rename some stuff on the root of the drive but that seems to happen less often than in my music folder.  Will update if it still occurs with F2k closed.